# Getting higher powers in modular arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How would I solve $7^{\ 345}+4^{2313} \equiv x \pmod 3$ ?

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$$7\equiv1\pmod3\implies 7^n\equiv1^n$$ for non-negative integer $n$